# Layout resource files not recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide

I refactored a resource_layout file but android studio didn't recognize the change so I deleted the file but didn't check the safe delete boxes.

Now whenever I create any layout resource files they are not recognized in my project. Any help would be very appreciated!

Also, the old layout resource file I had deleted is still recognized in my code (even though it should be breaking).

I tried cleaning my project, rebuilding my project, making my project.

I also tried checking through the terminal to see if the original layout resource file I deleted was still somewhere in the project but it isn't.

```
                    MaterialEditText edit_name =(MaterialEditText)enter_name_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
```

The enter_name_view doesn't exist anywhere but this line doesn't show any errors.